# How to count the values of an option in Power BI multiple choice list, List is Imported through SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-list, powerbi

I am trying to get the count value of 'standard' from the following in PowerBi:

Change Type:
Minor,
Standard,
Emergency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out myself by using the fields in the visualization in Power BI, where I have used the 'Matrix table' and inserted the 'Change Type' in Rows field and then in the 'Values' field I have added the Change Type again and clicked on the down arrow which is placed on the left of the column and selected Count from there and it worked perfectly.

I hope this will help people in the future.